# best way to execute something at a specific time

Tags: android

I'm writing on app which changes the airplanemode at a specific time.

How can I execute a airplanemode switch? With a alarmmanager or what?

Comment: So your question is not about "time" but on "how to enable airplane mode"?

Comment: i want to enable apm f. e. from 9am to 4pm afterwards i want to disable it

Comment: I dont think it is feasible to do programatically because you should require system level permissions to toggle the airplane mode. 
If you are developing a system app/rom, this is achievable by Alarm manager.

Answer (score 0):

> best way to execute something at a specific time

The only effective way to execute something at a specific time is to use `AlarmManager`, with a `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm type and a broadcast `PendingIntent`, where you do your work completely inside `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver()` (if it is short) or use a `WakeLock` and a `Service` to do the work (or possibly my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)).